# Serialize and Deserialize AjaxFileUploadEventArgs - No parameterless constructor defined'

Tags: c#, serialization, ajaxcontroltoolkit, javascriptserializer

I'm changing a webform website to use StateServer and now I'm trying to find a way to serialize and deserialize AjaxFileUploadEventArgs, my code so far:

In the html I have:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload
ID="AAA"
runat="server"
OnUploadComplete="OnUploadComplete"
ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
```

Server:

```
protected void OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs file)
        {
            UpdateListInSession(file);
        }

public static void UpdateListInSession(AjaxFileUploadEventArgs file)
{
  var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  var fileSerialized = serializer.Serialize(file);
}

public static AjaxFileUploadEventArgs GetLeadsListFromSession()
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    AjaxFileUploadEventArgs file = null;

    AjaxFileUploadEventArgs deserializeFile = 
         serializer.Deserialize<AjaxFileUploadEventArgs>(
            HttpContext.Current.Session[k_file] as string);

  return deserializeFile;
}
```

The error:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs'.'

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language you are using. And probably the error message already helps....

Comment: Is this the type you are trying to serialize?    [`AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs`](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUploadEventArgs.cs).  We need to know how to reproduce the problem to give you a working solution.

Comment: Added more details, thanks.

Comment: OK, but can you confirm it's the type from https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUploadEventArgs.cs that you are trying to deserialize?  Or if not can you provide a link or tag to the toolkit you are using?  Actually is it [tag:ajaxcontroltoolkit]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using [`AjaxFileUploadEventArgs.cs`](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUploadEventArgs.cs) from [ajaxcontroltoolkit](/questions/tagged/ajaxcontroltoolkit), the exception message is self-explanatory.  The serializer you are using, `JavaScriptSerializer`, can only construct and deserialize a type with a parameterless constructor, but as shown in its [reference source](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUploadEventArgs.cs#L8), `AjaxFileUploadEventArgs` only has a single constructor, which is parameterized:

```
public AjaxFileUploadEventArgs(string fileId, AjaxFileUploadState state, string statusMessage, string fileName, int fileSize, string contentType) {
        // Initialize fields
}
```

So, what are your options to deserialize this type?  Firstly, you could switch to [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) which supports parameterized constructors out of the box.  Once Json.NET is installed, if you do:

```
var deserializeFile = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AjaxFileUploadEventArgs>(jsonString);
```

Then it simply works.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pe4aoF).  Note that [Microsoft's own documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) for `JavaScriptSerializer` states:

> [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) should be used serialization and deserialization.

So this is likely the best solution.

If you cannot use Json.NET for whatever reason, you will need to write a custom [`JavaScriptConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) for `AjaxFileUploadEventArgs` such as the following:

```
public class AjaxFileUploadEventArgsConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var args = new AjaxFileUploadEventArgs
        (
            serializer.ConvertItemToTypeOrDefault<string>(dictionary, "FileId"),
            serializer.ConvertItemToTypeOrDefault<AjaxFileUploadState>(dictionary, "State"),
            serializer.ConvertItemToTypeOrDefault<string>(dictionary, "StatusMessage"),
            serializer.ConvertItemToTypeOrDefault<string>(dictionary, "FileName"),
            serializer.ConvertItemToTypeOrDefault<int>(dictionary, "FileSize"), 
            serializer.ConvertItemToTypeOrDefault<string>(dictionary, "ContentType")
        ) 
        { PostedUrl = serializer.ConvertItemToTypeOrDefault<string>(dictionary, "PostedUrl") };
        return args;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new[] { typeof(AjaxFileUploadEventArgs) }; }
    }
}

public static class JavaScriptSerializerExtensions
{
    public static T ConvertItemToTypeOrDefault<T>(this JavaScriptSerializer serializer, IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, string key)
    {
        object value;

        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            return default(T);

        return serializer.ConvertToType<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Then deserialize as follows:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new AjaxFileUploadEventArgsConverter() });
var deserializeFile = serializer.Deserialize<AjaxFileUploadEventArgs>(jsonString);
```